Is the output for ConvexHullRegion wrong in Mathematica 13.3?
The first example in the help for ConvexHullRegion is:
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2}];
\[ScriptCapitalR] = ConvexHullRegion[pts]
Region[\[ScriptCapitalR], Epilog -> {Black, Point[pts]}]

Its output contains Polygon[Number of points 9...] where 9 changes at every reevaluation.  However, in the plot, the number of points seems to be 50

It seems to me you are referring to the "Number of points: 50" in the documentation. For this, you should contact the Wolfram Technical Support. Otherwise, ConvexHullRegion works as expected, and it shows the number of points lying on the convex hull.

I can't find an email for Wolfram Technical Support

Under the Help menu, use Give Feedback ...

I don't see the problem.  The number of points in the convex hull for 50 random points is typically around 9 or so, and will change based on random seed.

RandomPolygon[{"Convex", 50}]

How do you find the vertices of the polytope defined by RandomPolygon?

No. The number of points is correct, because it is the number of points on the boundary, not the interior. This is precisely the number of points (i.e. vertices) needed to define the convex hull region (polygon). This explains why the number sometimes changes when the point cloud is changed.
